# filename and line number of Python script

Tags: python, debugging, file

How can I get the file name and line number in a Python script?

Exactly the file information we get from an exception traceback. In this case without raising an exception.

Answer (score 251):

Thanks to mcandre, the answer is:

```
#python3
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo

frameinfo = getframeinfo(currentframe())

print(frameinfo.filename, frameinfo.lineno)
```

Comment: Does using this method have any performance impact (like minor increase in run time or more CPU needed ) ?

Comment: @gsinha: Every function call has performance impact. You have to measure if this impact is acceptable for you.

Comment: So, if you like "one line" type answers use:
`import inspect
inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).lineno`

Comment: To expand on this, at what point is the line number "evaluated", in the second or third line? I.e does `frameinfo.lineno` give you the line numer when you evaluate it, or when you created it with `getframeinfo(currentframe())`?

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon it happens when `currentframe()` is called, which means you can't simplify this any more than `getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno` (if you only care about the line number and not the file name). See https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe

Answer (score 97):

Whether you use `currentframe().f_back` depends on whether you are using a
function or not.

Calling inspect directly:

```
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo

cf = currentframe()
filename = getframeinfo(cf).filename

print "This is line 5, python says line ", cf.f_lineno 
print "The filename is ", filename
```

Calling a function that does it for you:

```
from inspect import currentframe

def get_linenumber():
    cf = currentframe()
    return cf.f_back.f_lineno

print "This is line 7, python says line ", get_linenumber()
```

Comment: Plus one, for providing a solution in a callable function.  Very nice!

Comment: Always wanted to call from a function - this helps. THANK YOU

Comment: golang log style `def log(*args, **kwargs):
    cf = inspect.currentframe()
    print(f"{inspect.stack()[1][1]}:{cf.f_back.f_lineno}", *args, **kwargs)
`

Comment: i'm using a lambda ```line = lambda : currentframe().f_back.f_lineno``` with your solution, very nice

Answer (score 38):

Handy if used in a common file - prints file name, line number and function of the caller:

```
import inspect
def getLineInfo():
    print(inspect.stack()[1][1],":",inspect.stack()[1][2],":",
          inspect.stack()[1][3])
```

Answer (score 29):

Better to use sys also-

```
import sys
print(dir(sys._getframe()))
print(dir(sys._getframe().f_lineno)
print(sys._getframe().f_lineno)
```

The output is:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'f_back', 'f_builtins', 'f_code', 'f_exc_traceback', 'f_exc_type', 'f_exc_value', 'f_globals', 'f_lasti', 'f_lineno', 'f_locals', 'f_restricted', 'f_trace']
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__coerce__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__long__', '__lshift__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__oct__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
14
```

Comment: Should use `sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno`, especialy when used in a function, otherwise it will print the line where it's being called in the function.

Answer (score 23):

**Filename**:

```
__file__
# or
sys.argv[0]
```

**Line**:

```
inspect.currentframe().f_lineno
```

(not `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno` as mentioned above)

Comment: `NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined` on my Python interpreter: `Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep 26 2014, 15:59:23)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do/9271617#comment33090606_9271479

Comment: a function version, ```def __LINE__() -> int:
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno

def __FILE__() -> str:
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename```

Comment: @hanshenrik, copilot agrees with you

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` gives the command used to invoke

Answer (score 23):

In Python 3 you can use a variation on (This has been improved after a comment by Claudio):

```
def Deb(msg=""):
  print(f"Debug {sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno}: {msg}")
```

In code, you can then use:

```
Deb("Some useful information")
Deb()
```

To produce:

```
123: Some useful information
124:
```

Where the 123 and 124 are the lines that the calls are made from.

Comment: This is the simplest and the best, especially when `sys` is already imported.  `inspect` from other answers is overkill for my use case.

Comment: Hint: eliminate unnecessary code: if you change `Deb(msg=None)` to **`Deb(msg='')`** you can replace {`msg if msg is not None else ''`} with **`{msg}`**.

Comment: Good point, thanks - I've revised the answer.

Comment: I like that this gives the line number of the caller without an exotic import. But it doesn't give the module/filename of the caller, which makes it less helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Just to contribute,

there is a `linecache` module in python, here is two links that can help.

[linecache module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html#module-linecache)
[linecache source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/linecache.py)

In a sense, you can "dump" a whole file into its cache , and read it with linecache.cache data from class.

```
import linecache as allLines
## have in mind that fileName in linecache behaves as any other open statement, you will need a path to a file if file is not in the same directory as script
linesList = allLines.updatechache( fileName ,None)
for i,x in enumerate(lineslist): print(i,x) #prints the line number and content
#or for more info
print(line.cache)
#or you need a specific line
specLine = allLines.getline(fileName,numbOfLine)
#returns a textual line from that number of line
```

For additional info, for error handling, you can simply use

```
from sys import exc_info
try:
     raise YourError # or some other error
except Exception:
     print(exc_info() )
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a short function that prints the file name and line number.

```py
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo


def HERE(do_print=True):
    ''' Get the current file and line number in Python script. The line 
    number is taken from the caller, i.e. where this function is called. 

    Parameters
    ----------
    do_print : boolean
        If True, print the file name and line number to stdout. 

    Returns
    -------
    String with file name and line number if do_print is False.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> HERE() # Prints to stdout

    >>> print(HERE(do_print=False))
    '''
    frameinfo = getframeinfo(currentframe().f_back)
    filename = frameinfo.filename.split('/')[-1]
    linenumber = frameinfo.lineno
    loc_str = 'File: %s, line: %d' % (filename, linenumber)
    if do_print:
        print('HERE AT %s' % (loc_str))
    else:
        return loc_str
```

Usage:

```
HERE() # Prints to stdout
# Output: HERE AT File: model.py, line: 275

print(HERE(False)) # Retrieves string and prints it.
# Output: File: model.py, line: 276
```

Comment: very good idea.

Answer (score 7):

```
import inspect    

file_name = __FILE__
current_line_no = inspect.stack()[0][2]
current_function_name = inspect.stack()[0][3]

#Try printing inspect.stack() you can see current stack and pick whatever you want
```

Comment: Similar to `__file__`: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056048/filename-and-line-number-of-python-script#comment74661035_10623150

Answer (score 1):

Here's what works for me to get the line number in Python 3.7.3 in VSCode 1.39.2 (`dmsg` is my mnemonic for debug message):

```
import inspect

def dmsg(text_s):
    print (str(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno) + '| ' + text_s)
```

To call showing a variable `name_s` and its value:

```
name_s = put_code_here
dmsg('name_s: ' + name_s)
```

Output looks like this:

```
37| name_s: value_of_variable_at_line_37
```

Comment: Thanks @Steph! I came up with the following for my code:
def dbgline():
       print(f"{inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals['__file__']}:{inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno}")

Answer (score 1):

Golang style

```py
import inspect
import sys
import atexit

ERR_FILE = open('errors.log', 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
LOG_FILE = open('log.log', 'w+', encoding='utf-8')

def exit_handler():
    # ctrl + C works as well
    log("Exiting")
    ERR_FILE.close()
    LOG_FILE.close()

# close files before exit
atexit.register(exit_handler)

def log(*args, files=[sys.stdout, LOG_FILE]):
    # can also add timestamps etc.
    cf = inspect.currentframe()
    for f in files:
        print("DEBUG", f"{inspect.stack()[1][1]}:{cf.f_back.f_lineno}", *args, file=f)
        f.flush()

def log_err(*args, files=[ERR_FILE, sys.stderr]):
    cf = inspect.currentframe()
    for f in files:
        print("ERROR", f"{inspect.stack()[1][1]}:{cf.f_back.f_lineno}", *args, file=f)
        f.flush()

log("Hello World!")
log_err("error")
```

Output

```
DEBUG sample.py:29 Hello World!
ERROR sample.py:30 error
DEBUG sample.py:9 Exiting
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by many of the above answers and the console.log() function of JavaScript, I have deployed a pip package to serve this purpose.
Please check this out [here](https://pypi.org/project/print-position/).

### How to install?

Just install the package using the command:

```
pip3 install print_position
```

A simple example is (test.py):

```
from printPosition.printPosition import printPosition as print 
print("Test on line 2 from test.py")
print("Test on line 3 from test.py")



print("Test on line 7 from test.py")
```

The output of the above code is:

```
@/home/pranav/Desktop/GitHub/PrintPosition-pip/print-log/test.py: 2 
Test on line 2 from test.py
@/home/pranav/Desktop/GitHub/PrintPosition-pip/print-log/test.py: 3 
Test on line 3 from test.py
@/home/pranav/Desktop/GitHub/PrintPosition-pip/print-log/test.py: 7 
Test on line 7 from test.py
```

Please let me know if it helped you!
Also feel free to raise any issues/requests, everything is mentioned on the pip page [here](https://pypi.org/project/print-position/).

Answer (score 0):

People familiar with PHP's `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` might appreciate

```py
import inspect

def __FILE__() -> str:
    # ptyhon has a native __file__ 
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename

def __LINE__() -> int:
    # python has no native __line__, the closest thing I could find was: sys._getframe().f_lineno
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno
```

unfortunately they must be used with `()`, sample usage:

```py
print("file: " + __FILE__() + " line: " + str(__LINE__()) );
```

- wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/WABqQbLtEJdltVwV

(both are part of my collection of php-apis-ported-to-python, https://github.com/divinity76/phppy/blob/main/php.py )

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: @con what happens when you try it? an error? wrong line number? wrong file? fwiw here is the code running on Wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/WABqQbLtEJdltVwV

Comment: maybe I didn't implement the code correctly, a minimal example seems to work, the much larger project that I edited before didn't work, likely my own fault

Answer (score 0):

**sys._getframe().f_lineno** is BY FAR the most performant out of the 3 below execution line retrieval methods according to timeit() results.

```
# Prints the line # the call was executed from
print(sys._getframe().f_lineno) # METHOD #1
print(getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno) # METHOD #2
print(inspect.stack()[0][2]) # METHOD #3

# Number used for timeit() iterations
num = 10000

# Below Line: METHOD #1 - Fastest - 0.0011057000083383173 (~2000x faster than below)
print(timeit.timeit('sys._getframe().f_lineno', setup = 'from __main__ import sys', number = num))
# Below Line: METHOD #2 - 2nd Fastest - 2.3906398999970406 (~2.5x faster than below)
print(timeit.timeit('(getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno)', setup = 'from __main__ import currentframe, getframeinfo', number = num))
# Below Line: METHOD #3 - Slowest - 6.436119699996198 (~6,000x slower than fastest)
print(timeit.timeit('inspect.stack()[0][2]', setup = 'from __main__ import inspect', number = num))
```

I'm not super familiar with these methods so please comment if there are reasons that this test scenario doesn't reflect real-world performance, although based on the fact that if you change the number arg from 10,000 to 1,000 the results are also divided by 10 it does seem that these are accurate.