# How to determine file, function and line number?

Tags: python

In C++, I can print debug output like this:

```
printf(
   "FILE: %s, FUNC: %s, LINE: %d, LOG: %s\n",
   __FILE__,
   __FUNCTION__,
   __LINE__,
   logmessage
);
```

How can I do something similar in Python?

Comment: You always print error log like that? That's remarkable, since there is no `print` function in C++.

Comment: @Tomalak typo, in python thread now. :)

Comment: Once you go Python, you never go back (much).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There is a module named [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) which provides these information.

Example usage:

```
import inspect

def PrintFrame():
  callerframerecord = inspect.stack()[1]    # 0 represents this line
                                            # 1 represents line at caller
  frame = callerframerecord[0]
  info = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)
  print(info.filename)                      # __FILE__     -> Test.py
  print(info.function)                      # __FUNCTION__ -> Main
  print(info.lineno)                        # __LINE__     -> 13

def Main():
  PrintFrame()                              # for this line

Main()
```

However, please remember that there is an easier way to obtain the name of the currently executing file:

```
print(__file__)
```

Answer (score 13):

For example

```
import inspect
frame = inspect.currentframe()
# __FILE__
fileName  =  frame.f_code.co_filename
# __LINE__
fileNo = frame.f_lineno
```

There's more here http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Comment: And a simple way to get fileNo: `fileNo = frame.f_lineno`

Answer (score 12):

Building on geowar's answer:

```python
class __LINE__(object):
    import sys

    def __repr__(self):
        try:
            raise Exception
        except:
            return str(sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back.f_lineno)

__LINE__ = __LINE__()
```

If you normally want to use `__LINE__` in e.g. `print` (or any other time an implicit `str()` or `repr()` is taken), the above will allow you to omit the `()`s.

(Obvious extension to add a `__call__` left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: Why pack the `return` statement in a trivial (read: always on) try-raise-except triplet?

Comment: @Whaa, as opposed to what? The `return` *inspects the exception* I just raised, as a method of obtaining the stack. Presumably that isn't the only way, but at least Tugrul Ates seems (slightly) more complicated and requires a less-used `import`.

Comment: Understood. I missed the use of Python's silly implicit exception information mechanism.

Answer (score 12):

You can refer my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973480/1591700

```
import sys
print sys._getframe().f_lineno
```

You can also make lambda function

Answer (score 8):

wow, 7 year old question :)

Anyway, taking Tugrul's answer, and writing it as a `debug` type method, it can look something like:

```
def debug(message):
    import sys
    import inspect
    callerframerecord = inspect.stack()[1]
    frame = callerframerecord[0]
    info = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)
    print(info.filename, 'func=%s' % info.function, 'line=%s:' % info.lineno, message)

def somefunc():
    debug('inside some func')

debug('this')
debug('is a')
debug('test message')
somefunc()
```

Output:

```
/tmp/test2.py func=<module> line=12: this
/tmp/test2.py func=<module> line=13: is a
/tmp/test2.py func=<module> line=14: test message
/tmp/test2.py func=somefunc line=10: inside some func
```

Answer (score 7):

I was also interested in a __LINE__ command in python. 
My starting point was https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811020 and I extended it with a metaclass object. With this modification it has the same behavior like in C++.

```
import inspect

class Meta(type):
    def __repr__(self):
        # Inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811020
        callerframerecord = inspect.stack()[1]  # 0 represents this line
        # 1 represents line at caller
        frame = callerframerecord[0]
        info = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)
        # print(info.filename)  # __FILE__     -> Test.py
        # print(info.function)  # __FUNCTION__ -> Main
        # print(info.lineno)  # __LINE__     -> 13
        return str(info.lineno)

class __LINE__(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

print(__LINE__)  # print for example 18
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import inspect
    .
    .
    .
def __LINE__():
    try:
        raise Exception
    except:
        return sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back.f_lineno

def __FILE__():
    return inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_filename
    .
    .
    .
print "file: '%s', line: %d" % (__FILE__(), __LINE__())
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [tool](https://github.com/gruns/icecream) to answer this old yet new question!
I recommend using [`icecream`](https://github.com/gruns/icecream)!

> Do you ever use print() or log() to debug your code? Of course, you
> do. IceCream, or ic for short, makes print debugging a little sweeter.
>
> `ic()` is like `print()`, but better:
>
> 1. It prints both expressions/variable names and their values.
> 2. It's 40% faster to type.
> 3. Data structures are pretty printed.
> 4. Output is syntax highlighted.
> 5. It optionally includes program context: filename, line number, and parent function.

For example, I created a module `icecream_test.py`, and put the following code inside it.

```
from icecream import ic
ic.configureOutput(includeContext=True)
def foo(i):
    return i + 333

ic(foo(123))
```

Prints

```
ic| icecream_test.py:6 in <module>- foo(123): 456
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the line number in Python without importing the whole `sys` module...

First import the `_getframe` submodule:

```py
from sys import _getframe
```

Then call the `_getframe` function and use its' `f_lineno` property whenever you want to know the line number:

```py
print(_getframe().f_lineno)  # prints the line number
```

From the interpreter:

```py
>>> from sys import _getframe
... _getframe().f_lineno  # 2
```

Word of caution from the  official Python Docs:

> **CPython implementation detail**: This function should be used for internal and specialized purposes only. It is not guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python.

In other words: Only use this code for personal testing / debugging reasons.

See the Official Python Documentation on [`sys._getframe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) for more information on the sys module, and the `_getframe()` function / submodule.

*Based on [Mohammad Shahid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973535/4789202) (above).*

Answer (score 0):

```
import inspect
frame = inspect.currentframe()
print(f"{frame.f_lineno}\tdebugtext")
l = lambda: frame.f_lineno
print(f"{l()}\tdebugtext")
```

This prints:

```
3   debugtext
5   debugtext
```