# Getting function and line number where an error occurred in a python script

Tags: python, error-handling

How can I get where exactly in my code there was an error? I need to know if it was inside or outside a function and the absolute line number inside the script (or at least inside the function).

Looking at the very schematic example below this lines:

Let's say there's an error inside function *func_b*. I want to print: 
**Error in func_b, line 4**

Right now I'm using

```
sys.exc_info()[2].tb_lineno
```

to get the line number, but it prints:
**Error in my_script.py, line 8**
which is not what I want.

If there's an error before executing any function I want to print:
**Error in my_script.py, line 6**

```
def func_a():   
  #do something    
def func_b():   
  #do something
try:   
  #do something   
  func_a()   
  func_b()    
except Exception as e:   
  print(...) # print where error occurred.
```

Comment: I think this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810999/how-to-determine-file-function-and-line-number
of simple `print __file__`, and `print __line__` should work