# Pythons equivalent of #line in C

Tags: python

As you might know, there is the #line command in the C-preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#line 20 "abc"
int main() {
    printf("%i %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__); //outputs 22 abc
}
```

Is there something like this #line command in python? I want to change what is printed in exceptions.

Note: This is not the same question as in [How to determine file, function and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810999/how-to-determine-file-function-and-line-number), becaues they want to print the current line, I want to change it.

Comment: C doesn't have a `#line` command; that's a C *preprocessor* directive.

Comment: I know. Fixed it in the text but not in the title to make the title shorter.