# Is there way to get function called column location not only file and line information for Python?

Tags: python, logging, inspect

I'm implementing logging function in a static period, and getting id to identify where the function is called is necessary for this.
Currently the id is computed with serialization of 'inspect.stack()[1][1:]' by 'pickle' and I have created below python script for testing this feature.
I'm currently using 'inspect' module but it returns only filename, linenumber, source at that line.

```
import inspect
import hashlib


def loginfo_throttle():
    frame = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
    print(hashlib.md5(pickle.dumps(inspect.stack()[1][1:])).hexdigest())
    print(inspect.getframeinfo(frame))
    print('<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<')


def main():
    loginfo_throttle();loginfo_throttle()
    loginfo_throttle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is as below, and the first and second output is exactly same and this is the problem.

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
9ab15e3e3d106afca16e4155ac571152
Traceback(filename='spam.py', lineno=20, function='main', code_context=['    loginfo_throttle();loginfo_throttle()\n'], index=0)
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
9ab15e3e3d106afca16e4155ac571152
Traceback(filename='spam.py', lineno=20, function='main', code_context=['    loginfo_throttle();loginfo_throttle()\n'], index=0)
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2d63d9b94b68ba14989ffebed0b70ab2
Traceback(filename='spam.py', lineno=21, function='main', code_context=['    loginfo_throttle()\n'], index=0)
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

**Update**

What I'd like to do in actual is as below,
so distinguishing functions in same line using the called time is difficult.

```
import inspect
import pickle
import time


class LoggingThrottle(object):

    time_table = {}

    def __call__(self, period, msg):
        id = pickle.dumps(inspect.stack()[1][1:])
        now = time.time()
        last_time = self.time_table.get(id)
        if (last_time is None) or ((now - last_time) > period):
            print(msg)
            self.time_table[id] = now


logging_throttle = LoggingThrottle()


def main():
    for i in xrange(1000):
        logging_throttle(3, 'foo'); logging_throttle(3, 'spam')
        logging_throttle(3, 'bar')
        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This outputs only 'foo' and 'bar'.

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `time()` to distinguish functions called within one line.

```
import inspect
import hashlib
import pickle
from time import time


def loginfo_throttle():
    frame = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    print('>'*30)
    t = time()
    print(hashlib.md5(pickle.dumps((t, inspect.stack()[1][1:]))).hexdigest())
    print(t, inspect.getframeinfo(frame))
    print('<'*30)


def main():
    loginfo_throttle();loginfo_throttle()
    loginfo_throttle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
5576395790524ffafbc8e3c257580697
(1464942290.227, Traceback(filename='<ipython-input-70-f8a8af94e830>', lineno=16, function='main', code_context=[u'    loginfo_throttle();loginfo_throttle()\n'], index=0))
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
a56f921a23caef7f5d40713141a53b55
(1464942290.354, Traceback(filename='<ipython-input-70-f8a8af94e830>', lineno=16, function='main', code_context=[u'    loginfo_throttle();loginfo_throttle()\n'], index=0))
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
16e9e10e253c42a4eeb5b5c42911de19
(1464942290.482, Traceback(filename='<ipython-input-70-f8a8af94e830>', lineno=17, function='main', code_context=[u'    loginfo_throttle()\n'], index=0))
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Maybe this does not work in my case. I updated the question, so please read under the **Update** section.

Comment: All I can suggest is to add argument to `id`, e.g. : `id = pickle.dumps((msg, inspect.stack()[1][1:]))`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, by getting column in source code as below, seeing this post. [How to find column number in Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044872/how-to-find-column-number-in-python-code)

```
import inspect
import pickle
import time


class LoggingThrottle(object):

    time_table = {}

    def __call__(self, period, msg):
        caller = inspect.stack()[1]
        frame, _, lineno, _, code, _ = caller
        caller_id = (
            inspect.getabsfile(frame),
            code,
            lineno,
            frame.f_lasti,
        )
        # print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
        # print(caller_id)
        # print('<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<')
        caller_id = pickle.dumps(caller_id)
        now = time.time()
        last_time = self.time_table.get(caller_id)
        if (last_time is None) or ((now - last_time) > period):
            print(msg)
            self.time_table[caller_id] = now


logging_throttle = LoggingThrottle()


def main():
    for i in xrange(1000):
        logging_throttle(3, 'foo'); logging_throttle(3, 'spam')
        logging_throttle(3, 'bar')
        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```