# Python - print() - debugging -show file and line number

Tags: python, debugging, printing

When using print() in python, is it possible to print where it was called? So the output will look like var_dump in php with xdebug. Eg. I have script D:\Something\script.py, and at line 50, there is a print("sometest"), so the output will look like this:

```
D:\Somethinq\script.py:50 sometest
```

Or is there any module that could achieve this? In large projects, it's really hard to manage where these prints came from.

Answer (score 13):

So, using answers provided in [filename and line number of python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056048/filename-and-line-number-of-python-script) , this function can be called instead of print(), and prints line number before every output:

```
from inspect import currentframe

def debug_print(arg):
    frameinfo = currentframe()
    print(frameinfo.f_back.f_lineno,":",arg)
```