# How to add code line number using structlog

Tags: structlog

Using python standard logging module, the line number for the originating log call can be added using: `%(lineno)s.`

How can this be accomplished using structlog?

Answer (score 10):

According to [official docs](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#rendering-within-structlog), you may add

```
structlog.configure(
        processors=[
            # ...
            # Add callsite parameters.
            structlog.processors.CallsiteParameterAdder(
                [CallsiteParameter.FILENAME,
                CallsiteParameter.FUNC_NAME,
                CallsiteParameter.LINENO],
            ),
            # ...
        ],
```

So, I guess there is no need to write a custom processor for this. It was hard to find in the official docs though.

Comment: Important: This processor cannot detect the correct callsite for invocation of async functions. Reference: https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/api.html#structlog.processors.CallsiteParameterAdder

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**

Structlog version 21.5.0 introduced the [CallsiteParameter processor](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/_modules/structlog/processors.html#CallsiteParameter), so this should be a much more straightforward process right now, as [@vitvlkv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72320473/289011) shows.

---

I had a similar need and I ended up creating a [custom processor](http://www.structlog.org/en/stable/examples.html#processors)

I took a look to [what `structlog` does](https://github.com/hynek/structlog/blob/master/src/structlog/_frames.py#L38) to output the module and line number when it is told to *"pretend"* to format in a compatible mode with the `logging` library (meaning: when it's using a regular `stdlib.LoggerFactory`) and I found inspiration in that. The key were the following words...

> By using structlog’s structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory, it is also ensured that variables like function names and line numbers are expanded correctly in your log format.

... from [this documentation page](http://www.structlog.org/en/stable/configuration.html#logger-factories)

The code seems to keep looking for execution frames until it finds one that is in a non logging-related module.

I have all the setup for `structlog` inside a module called `my_libs.util.logger` so I want to get the first frame that is NOT inside that module. In order to do that, I told it to add my logging-related `my_libs.util.logger` to those exclusions. That's what the `additional_ignores` in the code below does.

In the example I hardcoded the module's name (`'my_libs.util.logger'`) in the exclusion list for clarity, but if you have a similar setup you'll probably be better off using `__name__` instead. What this does is ignoring execution frames that exist because of the logging machinery in place. You can look at it as a way of ignoring calls that may have occurred as part of the process of actually logging the message. Or, otherwise said, calls that happened *after* the `logging.info("Foo")` that happened in the actual module/line that you *do* want to output.

Once it finds the *right* frame, extracting any kind of information (module name, function name, line number... ) is very easy, particularly using the [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html). I chose to output the module name and the line number, but more fields could be added.

```py
# file my_libs/util/logger.py
import inspect
from structlog._frames import _find_first_app_frame_and_name

def show_module_info_processor(logger, _, event_dict):
    # If by any chance the record already contains a `modline` key,
    # (very rare) move that into a 'modline_original' key
    if 'modline' in event_dict:
        event_dict['modline_original'] = event_dict['modline']
    f, name = _find_first_app_frame_and_name(additional_ignores=[
        "logging",
        'my_libs.util.logger',  # could just be __name__
    ])
    if not f:
        return event_dict
    frameinfo = inspect.getframeinfo(f)
    if not frameinfo:
        return event_dict
    module = inspect.getmodule(f)
    if not module:
        return event_dict

    if frameinfo and module:
        # The `if` above is probably redundant, since we already
        # checked for frameinfo and module but... eh... paranoia.
        event_dict['modline'] = '{}:{}'.format(
            module.__name__,
            frameinfo.lineno,
        )
    return event_dict

def setup_structlog(env=None):
    # . . . 
    ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))

    logging.getLogger().handlers = [ch]

    processors = [
        structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
        structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
        # . . . more . . . 
        show_module_info_processor,  # THIS!!!
        structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
        structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        # . . . more . . . 
    ]

    # . . . more . . . 
    structlog.configure_once(
        logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
        wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger,
        context_class=structlog.threadlocal.wrap_dict(dict),
        processors=processors,
    )
```

This produces an output like:

```
server_1                           
| INFO  [my_libs.hdfs] 2019-07-01 01:01:01 [info     ] Initialized HDFS               
[my_libs.hdfs] modline=my_libs.hdfs:31
```

Comment: This solution worked great for me, for the most part unedited.  I only changed the 'could just be \_\_name\_\_' line to '\_\_name\_\_' as well as adding an 'import inspect' statement.

Comment: Thank you @DavidW. Glad this helped. I'm gonna add the `import inspect` to the code

Comment: This is excellent @BorrajaX!  Tweaked my copy a little bit to also include `frameinfo.function` as well.  Worth noting that `_find_first_app_frame_and_name` might break in future versions of structlog; recommend including your own copy of this in your answer.  Or better yet, submit a PR and get this into the library - very useful!

Comment: If anyone gets a `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`: You've put your custom processor BELOW the JSONRenderer. Don't do that. *Order of processors matter!!!*

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this answer to the more general question of how to get a line number.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3056270/5909155
This cannot be bound to the logger with log.bind(...) because it has to be evaluated each time you log. Thus, you should add a key-value pair like this

```
logger.log(..., lineno=inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).lineno)
```

each time. Maybe wrap this in a function, though, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20372465/5909155
Don't forget to

```
import inspect
```