# Python equivalent to C++ __LINE__

Tags: python

A useful print for debugging in C++ is

```
std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
```

Of course you can simply print a string with the line number, for example:

```
std::cout << "this is line 54" << std::endl;
```

but it won't keep changing the line number when you move it around. 
Is there any equivalent macro in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filename and line number of python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056048/filename-and-line-number-of-python-script)

Comment: @rkersh you are right, however I think the answer here is the best one, so not sure how to proceed in this case (I feel closing the question removes valuable knowledge). Maybe the the user from the accepted answer could reply on the other question and then I can suppress this one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a function, so you don't have to expand it everywhere

```
import sys

def LINE():
    return sys._getframe(1).f_lineno


print('This is line', LINE())
```

TBH I've never understood the point of the `inspect` module at all.

Comment: The inspect module is meant to be public ways of accessing information about Python objects in a portal manner, say, for example, if you need a Python implementation other than CPython (say, PyPi, Jython or IronPython). You should not use `_getframe`, explicitly, "CPython implementation detail: This function should be used for internal and specialized purposes only. It is not guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python." If you use inspect, you can guarantee it works on more than just CPython. Using `getframeinfo(currentframe())` works everywhere, `_getframe` may break.

Answer (score 11):

No macro, but you can do

```
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo

print(getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno)
```

To get the current line number in Python.

The "current line number" will be the line where `currentframe()` is evaluated, FYI.

Answer (score 9):

Define a class with the `__str__` method returns the current line number:

```py
import inspect

class LineNo:
    def __str__(self):
        return str(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno)


__line__ = LineNo()
```

Now it's more similar to C++:

```
print(__file__, __line__)
```

Comment: This is so sneaky, I love it.  Would upvote more than once if I could.

Comment: Agree. Very sneaky indeed. Went into the toolbox from where I will just import `__line__` from now on.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution the shortest, which seems to be not implementation specific:

```
import inspect
def __LINE__(): return inspect.stack()[1].lineno
```

For some reason I like to use `stack` as it returns a list. If I need to go deeper then I use `stack()[<n>].frame`.

**UPDATE**
I have checked the performance! `sys._getframe(1).f_lineno` or `inspect.currentframe().f_back` is much faster! Instead of calling my `__LINE__()` I put directly the `_getframe(1)` solution. If called 1e6 times, the gain is over 10 minutes!

**UPDATE2**
I think I have found an even faster way. If performance does count and the `__LINE__` is used inside a single module, then this can be used:

```
import inspect
__LINE__ = inspect.currentframe()
print(__LINE__.f_lineno)
print(__LINE__.f_lineno)
```

It prints (a little bit unexpectedly):

```
3
4
```

Comment: if you are unfortunate enough to be running python <3.5, you want: `return inspect.stack()[1][2]`, as the frame isnt a named tuple until 3.5.