# Python - Get the source code of the line that called me

Tags: python, inspect

Using the python inspect module, in a function, I would like to get the source code of the line that called that function.

So in the following situation:

```
def fct1():
    # Retrieve the line that called me and extract 'a'
    return an object containing name='a'

a = fct1()
```

I would like to retrieve the string "a = fct1()" in fct1

All I can do so far is to retrieve the code of the whole module with :

```
code = inspect.getsource(sys._getframe().f_back)
```

Please note that fct1() can be called many times in the main module.

Eventually, what I want is to retrieve the variable name "a" which is easy if I can get s = "a = fct1()" in fct1() :

```
a_name = s.split("=")[0].strip()
```

Comment: So you want the code in a variable, not actually find the code on the editor, right?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/427504/19330634) help you ?

Comment: l -_- l, no, I want the reverse. I want the caller in the called.

Comment: NicoCaldo, I want  s = "a = fct1()" in the fct1() then I will  s.split[0] myself to get "a". I updated my question.  Thanks

Comment: @u2gilles Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056048/filename-and-line-number-of-python-script help?

Comment: It would be cool to have this as a decorator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A really dumb solution would be to capture a stack trace and take the 2nd line:

```
import traceback

def fct1():
    stack = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)
    print(traceback.format_list(stack)[0].split('\n')[1].strip())  # prints "a = fct1()"
    return None

a = fct1()
```

@jtlz2 asked for it in a decorator

```
import traceback

def add_caller(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        stack = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)
        func(*args, caller=traceback.format_list(stack)[0].split('\n')[1].strip(), **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@add_caller
def fct1(caller):
    print(caller)

fct1()
```

And it does work

Comment: Sure it works. Fantastic. Now I can easilly retrieve the variable name 'a'.  Thanks a million.